Frege's implication theory
In a comment in the answer to a question I previously posted, someone said

MacColl asserted that the Boolean translation of "Every X is A" as XA=X does not work due to the "ivalid" 0A=0. Russell replied that there is no error "0A=0 means 'every member of the class which has no member is an A,' or "for every value of x, ' x is a member of the class which has no members' implies 'x is an A '."

However, this debate is a debate between MacColl and Russell, and when I found it, it seemed that the fundamental problem that led to the debate about logic such as XA = X and 0A = 0 was due to the content of Frege's implication. So, if my thoughts are right, that's fine, but if my thoughts are wrong, I want to find out about the theory or logic that is the fundamental reason why the XA=X, 0A=0 debate occurred.

Why do you think that Frege's doctrines are "directly" involved in the discussion? Russell's paper was published in 1905 and it explicitly ref ro his book The Principles (1903) where Frege's view were discussed in the Appendix. Prior to it, the mainstream logical school was that of Alegebraic Logic that is the context of MacColl's work.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Hello, thank you for your comment.  I searched Google and saw an article saying that the fundamental reason for the difference of opinion between Russell and MacColl was the implication theory, so I thought like this.

There is an link.
The key-point of the Russell-MacColl's debate about the boolean formula 0A=0 is that for MacColl the symbol 0 means "the class  of non-existents" while for Russell the symbol 0 means the non-existent class (today: the empty class).
Thus, 0A=0 for Russell must be read as the modern: "for every value of x, if x is a member of the empty class, then x is a member of the class A", that is true for every value of x because it is an hypothetical (a conditional statement) with antecedent false.
For Frege's reading of categorical statements and the square of oppositions, see Begriffscrifft (1879) §12 (page 27 of van Heijenoort's edition).
As you can see, Frege's reading is the same used by Russell in the Mind paper: The Existential Import of Propositions (1905).
See Ch.7.3.6 Russell versus MacColl of Ivor Grattan-Guinness, The Search for Mathematical Roots (1870-1940): Logics, set theories, and the foundations of mathematics from Cantor through Russell to Gödel (Princeton UP, 2000).
And see (but MacColl is not considered) Hans Sluga, Frege against the Booleans (NDJFL, 1987).
